# Python - ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type when using Sqlite

Tags: json, python-2.7, loops, dictionary, sqlite

So I'm new to python and am trying to put some data into a DB using Sqlite.
The data is a JSON with a list of dictionaries. The last entry of every dictinary is another list with dictionaries (see data below for first entry in the file). Pulling the data out of each dictionary in the list is fine except for the last part (that is a list of dictionaries). I can't get the itterating over it right. I put it into a function in my code to be able to call diferent url's (the error message still refers to 'WriteToFactionSpread', the name of the function)

Data: https://eddb.io/archive/v5/systems_populated.json

My code:

```
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)

input = json.loads(uh.read())


cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FactionSpread(minor_faction_id 
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, state_id INTEGER, influence INTEGER, state TEXT)''')
conn.commit()


for i in input:
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO FactionSpread (minor_faction_id, state_id, influence, state )VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', (i['minor_faction_presences'][0]['minor_faction_id'], i['minor_faction_presences'][1]['state_id']
            , i['minor_faction_presences'][2]['influence'], i['minor_faction_presences'][3]['state']))

conn.commit()
uh.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\EliteDangerous\trial.py", line 34, in <module>
    WriteToFactionSpread(ab)
  File "E:\Python\EliteDangerous\trial.py", line 27, in WriteToFactionSpread
    (i['minor_faction_presences'][0]['minor_faction_id']))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

---

(I hope the formatting isn't too messed up copy/pasting it here, but I think it'll be ok).

I didn't copy paste in the actual data because it would crowd it up a bit but the link goes to a JSON file with data from the game Elite Dangerous.

Tried some different ways but I'm at a loss at the moment, I'm still green.

Comment: What exactly are the four parameter values?

Comment: Should be an integer, integer, integer and text. See below for an example. I also tried switching the "influence" to text (and some others aswell, just to check).
"minor_faction_id":31816, "state_id":80, "influence":null, "state":"None"

Comment: Second example: 
 "minor_faction_id":37949,"state_id":64,"influence":7.1,"state":"Civil War"

Comment: I did no ask what they *should be* but what they *are*. :) What is the output of `print (i['minor_faction_presences'][0]['minor_faction_id'], i['minor_faction_presences'][1]['state_id'], i['minor_faction_presences'][2]['influence'], i['minor_faction_presences'][3]['state'])`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but tried it out now (printed out the type(<data>))
For the 1st it returns: int
The second returns: int, Nonetype
The thirth returns: int, Nonetype, float
The last one doesnt return anything (so guess that one is empty all the way).

Comment: Isnt it possible to not enter any data? Shoudnt it just give 'Null'?

Comment: Why are there multiple outputs for a single value? Please edit your question and show the exact code you're using, and the exact output.

Comment: The code i used is this below for the first type. I changed what part of the data it wouldprint the type of to check all four of them. Above I gave the different types it returnd while looping throught the data. 
for i in input:
  try:
   print type(i['minor_faction_presences'][0]['minor_faction_id'])

  except:
   print 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
   continue

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit".